# javascript can't find the image file (Rails 4 app)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, google-maps, asset-pipeline

I have a ruby on rails 4 app. In `app/assets/javascripts`, I created a file `map.js` to draw some custom markers on google map:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: false,
  title: 'Hi',
  icon: 'icon1.png'
});
```

Everything is working fine, except it can't find `icon.png` and gives me the error message `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=icon1)`. The problem is most likely with how to write the file address, because if I change the code to `icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png'` everything works perfectly and it displays the marker on the map.
How can I find out how to solve the problem? I looked in `log/development` but didn't find anything useful there.
Where should I put `icon1.png` and how should refer to its address?

Please note I can't use rails helpers, etc in `map.js`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use images in your js file then first of all you'll have to change your js file to **`maps.js.erb`** and then you can access your assets by [`rails asset_path`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which will allow you to access your images , so you can have this in your js file

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  draggable: false,
  title: 'Hi',
  icon: "<%= asset_path('icon1.png') %>"  //this will look for an image "icon1.png" in assets/images
});
```

**Edit:**

[Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) basically concatenate assets, which can reduce the number of requests that a browser makes. If you look at rails guides it says

`Sprockets concatenates all JavaScript files into one master .js file and all CSS files     into one master .css file. Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that the file is cached by the web browser`

So you can't specify your *assets path by a static url* for this reason we use `rails asset_path` which will make proper url for your assets

Comment: Thanks. So isn't there any way to do this without changing to `.js.erb`? Is there any downsides (lower performance, speed, etc) to having a `.js.erb` in `app/assets/javascripts`?

Comment: @user2725109 updated my answer and also we have used `<%= asset_path('icon1.png') %>` so this will look for an image `icon1.png` and not `icon.png` in your `app/assets/images`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use gem [`js_assets`](https://github.com/kavkaz/js_assets)

In your application.js

```
//= require app_assets
```

This directive adds the method asset_path in the global scope.

Add to filter files `*.png`. To do this, add initizlizer:

```
# config/initializers/js_assets.rb

JsAssets::List.allow << '*.png'
```

To get the path to the file `icon1.png` depending on the environment

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: false,
    title: 'Hi',
    icon: asset_path('icon1.png')
});
```