# Vegas function is not loading images in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get my background images to load using the vegas function in my js file.  But it is not able to find the images in my rails asset pipeline for some reason. I've tried "../images/bg1.pg" as well but that did not work either.

**Error shown in console"

```
GET:  http://hostname/images/bg1.jpg not found
```

**Vegas function in js file:**

```
// Image background
    $.vegas({ src: '/images/bg1.jpg'
    });

    $.vegas('overlay', {
        src:'/images/06.png'
    });
```

**Location of where my JS files are stored in my asset pipeline:**

app/assets/javascripts

**Location of where my images are located:**

app/assets/images

Comment: does `/assets/images/bg1.jpg` work?

Comment: no, i tried that before posting to SO.

Comment: okay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546688/javascript-cant-find-the-image-file-rails-4-app seems to be relevant to your issue

Comment: That worked thanks pgoggijr!